# How to fetch images and videos together from external apps using intents android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I wish to launch an intent which can allow me to choose images and videos together ath the same time. Currently I see that I can set type of intent as image or as video but not both together.

```
      Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.OPENABLE");

  intent.setType("image/*");
      OR
  intent.setType("video/*");
```

Please suggest

Thanks